# Printing a table in Python

Tags: python, loops, nested, tabular

I have an assignment to create a 10 by 10 table in Python and I'm using the end "\t" within my print function to prevent it from creating a new line. But, I need it to start a new line after of course 10 characters. How can I make it do that? Here's my code:

```
product = 0
for x in range(1,11):
    for y in range(1,11):
        product = x * y
        print(product, end="\t")
```

I need it to look something like this:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   ...
2   4   6   8   10  12  ...
3   6   9   12  15  18  ...
```

Comment: `print()` right after the inner loop.

Comment: @zondo what if she uses 2.x version of Python? I would rather suggest `print("")`.

Comment: @mwarzynski: Python 2.x does not have the `end` keyword because `print` isn't a function.

Comment: @zondo Okay, thanks. Good to know.

Comment: You can use the ``print`` function in python 2.6+ using ``from __future__ import print_function`` as the first line of code in your script.

Answer (score 1):

This is using *alignement* options from the `format` method.

```
product = 0
for x in range(1,11):
    for y in range(1,11):
        product = x * y
        print('{:<4}'.format(product), end='')
    print()
```

Reference: [Format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings)

Comment: I think this is a bit past where I'm at in my class right now but I'll play with it anyways to see what it does :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think all you would need to add to get what you want is to print a new line in your inner loop like so:

```
product = 0
for x in range(1,11):
    print()
    for y in range(1,11):
        product = x * y
        print(product, end="\t")
```

On the third line it'll start a new line after 10.
The output will look like this:

`1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10

2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20

3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30

4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40

5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50

6   12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60

7   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70

8   16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80

9   18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90

10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100`

Comment: `print()` automatically adds a new line to whatever is being printed. When you print a new line, you're actually adding two. Just use `print()` with no arguments.

Comment: You probably want to more the `print()` line to after the inner loop. Otherwise you print a blank line at the start, and then leave the console cursor at the end of the last line!

Comment: Hmm putting it inside the inner loop didn't seem to work. That seems to cancel the end argument and everything is starting a new line again even with the other print statement after it.

Comment: Got it! if I put it like so:
product = 0
    for x in range(1,11):
        for y in range(1,11):
            product = x * y
            print(product, end="\t")
        print()

It works now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For fun, this can be done as a one liner with a bit of list comprehension and the `join` method

```
print('\n'.join(['\t'.join([str(x*y) for x in range(1,11)]) for y in range(1,11)]))
```