# Multiplication table in python doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a Multiplication table program. My problem is that the program cannot print to the right side.

The program will ask the user for start and stop. For example:

```
    start_number = 2
    stop_number = 4
```

Output should be like this:

```
2 x 1 = 2    3 x 1 = 3    4 x 1 = 4
2 x 2 = 4    3 x 2 = 6    4 x 2 = 8
2 x 3 = 6    3 x 3 = 9    4 x 3 = 12
2 x 4 = 8    3 x 4 = 12   4 x 4 = 16
2 x 5 = 10   3 x 5 = 15   4 x 5 = 20
2 x 6 = 12   3 x 6 = 18   4 x 6 = 24
2 x 7 = 14   3 x 7 = 21   4 x 7 = 28
2 x 8 = 16   3 x 8 = 24   4 x 8 = 32
2 x 9 = 18   3 x 9 = 27   4 x 9 = 36
2 x 10 = 20  3 x 10 = 30  4 x 10 = 40
2 x 11 = 22  3 x 11 = 33  4 x 11 = 44
2 x 12 = 24  3 x 12 = 36  4 x 12 = 48
```

This is my code :

```
start = int(input("Enter start number : "))
stop = int(input("Enter stop number : "))
def multi_num(start,stop):
    for i in range(start, stop+1):
        for j in range(1, 13):
            print("%d x %d = %d" % (i, j, i * j))
multi_num(start, stop)
```

This is my output:

```
2 x 1 = 2
2 x 2 = 4
2 x 3 = 6
2 x 4 = 8
2 x 5 = 10
2 x 6 = 12
2 x 7 = 14
2 x 8 = 16
2 x 9 = 18
2 x 10 = 20
2 x 11 = 22
2 x 12 = 24
3 x 1 = 3
3 x 2 = 6
3 x 3 = 9
3 x 4 = 12
3 x 5 = 15
3 x 6 = 18
3 x 7 = 21
3 x 8 = 24
3 x 9 = 27
3 x 10 = 30
3 x 11 = 33
3 x 12 = 36
4 x 1 = 4
4 x 2 = 8
4 x 3 = 12
4 x 4 = 16
4 x 5 = 20
4 x 6 = 24
4 x 7 = 28
4 x 8 = 32
4 x 9 = 36
4 x 10 = 40
4 x 11 = 44
4 x 12 = 48
```

I tried to use `end=" "` but it's not working - the program prints output in one line:

```
2 x 1 = 22 x 2 = 42 x 3 = 62 x 4 = 82 x 5 = 102 x 6 = 122 x 7 =  142 x 8 = 162 x 9 = 182 x 10 = 202 x 11 = 222 x 12 = 243 x 1 = 33 x 2 = 63 x 3 = 93 x 4 = 123 x 5 = 153 x 6 = 183 x 7 = 213 x 8 = 243 x 9 = 273 x 10 = 303 x 11 = 333 x 12 = 364 x 1 = 44 x 2 = 84 x 3 = 124 x 4 = 164 x 5 = 204 x 6 = 244 x 7 = 284 x 8 = 324 x 9 = 364 x 10 = 404 x 11 = 444 x 12 = 48
```

Comment: You'll have to format it yourself -- refer to [loops - Printing a table in Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244717/printing-a-table-in-python) for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to use `end=" "` but it's not working

It's definitely working though: `end=" "` will suppress the newline used by default, so no newline => everything is on the same line. It does exactly what it's supposed to.

The actual problem is that you're thinking in columns but terminals work line by line: you print a line, go to the next one, print the next line, ..., like a tape or typewriter (which is very much what they were, the original computer IO were a souped up typewriter for input and a line printer outputting [continuous form paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_stationery) for output).

You *could* munge your output so that it's generated by column then the columns are pasted together before printing, or switch the terminal to *raw mode* and manage the terminal as [a TUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface).

But the simplest solution is to work your thinking around what the terminal wants instead of what you expect, and perform line-wise generation: switch your two loops around so that every `i` is used for each `j`, generating a full line, then add a newline before getting to the next `j`:

```py
start = int(input("Enter start number : "))
stop = int(input("Enter stop number : "))
def multi_num(start,stop):
    for j in range(1, 13):
        for i in range(start, stop+1):
            print(f"{i} x {j} = {i*j}", end='\t')
        print()
multi_num(start, stop)
```

result:

```
Enter start number : 2
Enter stop number : 5
2 x 1 = 2   3 x 1 = 3   4 x 1 = 4   5 x 1 = 5   
2 x 2 = 4   3 x 2 = 6   4 x 2 = 8   5 x 2 = 10  
2 x 3 = 6   3 x 3 = 9   4 x 3 = 12  5 x 3 = 15  
2 x 4 = 8   3 x 4 = 12  4 x 4 = 16  5 x 4 = 20  
2 x 5 = 10  3 x 5 = 15  4 x 5 = 20  5 x 5 = 25  
2 x 6 = 12  3 x 6 = 18  4 x 6 = 24  5 x 6 = 30  
2 x 7 = 14  3 x 7 = 21  4 x 7 = 28  5 x 7 = 35  
2 x 8 = 16  3 x 8 = 24  4 x 8 = 32  5 x 8 = 40  
2 x 9 = 18  3 x 9 = 27  4 x 9 = 36  5 x 9 = 45  
2 x 10 = 20 3 x 10 = 30 4 x 10 = 40 5 x 10 = 50 
2 x 11 = 22 3 x 11 = 33 4 x 11 = 44 5 x 11 = 55 
2 x 12 = 24 3 x 12 = 36 4 x 12 = 48 5 x 12 = 60
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```py
start = int(input("Enter start number : "))
stop = int(input("Enter stop number : "))
def multi_num(start,stop):
    for j in range(1, 13):
        line = ['{} X {} = {}'.format(n, j, n*j) for n in range(start,stop+1)]
        print('\t'.join(line))
multi_num(start, stop)
```